# Command line connection string for EF core database update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using ASP.NET Core and EF Core, I am trying to apply migrations to the database. However, the login in the connection string in `appsettings.json` that the app will use has only CRUD access, because of security concerns, so it can't create tables and columns, etc. So, when I run:

```
dotnet ef database update -c MyDbContextName -e Development
```

I want to tell it to use a different connection string, but I don't know if this can be done? Basically, I want to use two different connection strings, one for deployment and one for running the app. Is this possible? Is there a better approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Keep both connection strings in `appsettings.json`. Inherit a child context class from the main one and override `OnConfiguring` with another connection string:

```
public class ScaffoldContext : MyDbContextName 
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string scaffoldConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["scaffoldConnStr"].ConnectionString;

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(scaffoldConnStr);
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
dotnet ef database update -c ScaffoldContext
```

Comment: Thanks Ilya. I've accepted your answer because it is correct, but do you know of a way to do this so that the other connection string is not in appsettings.json, I would like to pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: @NemanjaPerovic, unfortunately `dotnet ef database update` doesn't supply an option to override a connection string. However, you can specify Environment and DbContext options, so I suggest it is easiest way to change connstr. Another way may be to set an environment variable and then read it inside your `ScaffoldContext` but I never applied it yet because it looks too tricky.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov are you able to run that command straight from Azure staging/production environment? I tried but it complains it cannot find *dotnet-ef*. Or that can be run from a local machine, takind advantage of conn. string pointing to remote staging/production DB? TA

Comment: @superjos I only used that command from local machine. You can set the environment (Development, Test, etc.) to override the connection string on scaffold.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Not really - I think we just did the DB updates manually for a while, and the project never went much further.

Comment: Genius! Also, the added context and services factory in Startup can be bracketed by compiler #if statements to avoid accidents at run-time.

Comment: See secret-manager at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows#secret-manager

Comment: What project does this go into? The startup project or the efcore project?

Answer (score 58):

In EF Core 5.0, you will pass the connection string in the command line like this,

```
dotnet ef database update --connection "connection string"
```

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#new-command-line-parameters-for-namespaces-and-connection-strings

Comment: Just in case if anybody will face the issue like I did. `--connection` works but you must update not only CLI but also project references to version 5.0+

Comment: But this doesn't work for migrations right?

Comment: @Daniel give a try and update here

Comment: I tried and it didn't work for me that's why i was asking But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Daniel sorry I tried with EF Core 5 that time and never worked after that

Answer (score 7):

if you are using the `Package Manager Console` use the following command:

`Update-Database -Connection "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"`

Answer (score 6):

In a Linux terminal:

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
dotnet ef database update
```

Where ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT match with appsettings.Development.json and the properly connectionstring configured.

Answer (score 5):

I liked the idea of a scaffolding DbContext, but I found some issues (somehow solvable, I guess) and also some consideration on where to keep connection strings. Those led me to another, more crude solution, so I thought I'd share all that here.

This is about the general approach, and consequent solution:

1. I don't like to store staging/production connection strings under source control. So I would pass that through an environment variable set in a temporary command window (or maybe on the fly on command-line, although I was not able to make that work). At that point, if I'm setting an environment variable, I might as well *override* initial connection string used by `MyDbContextName`, instead of adding a new one. Thus the whole scaffolding DB context thing could be overcome doing this way.

Other issues I found along the way:

1. Initial DbContext had dependencies injected into constructor, so child context had to to the same. This made `dotnet ef` commands complain about missing parameterless constructor.
2. To overcome that, child context as well was registered at startup with `.AddDbContext<ChildDbContext>(...)`. This also required for ChildDbContext to be injected both with a `DbContextOptions<ParentDbContext>` as well as  a `DbContextOptions<ChildDbContext>`. After that, `dotnet-ef` still found issues with instantiating ChildDbContext, as that needed also a dependency on `IConfiguration` which could not be found. Maybe (?) this is due to the fact that `dotnet-ef` does not run through the whole application startup.

As I said, I guess the issues could be solved after all, but still I'm questioning the real value of a scaffolding context in case you don't want to save connection strings in dedicated appsettings files. One counter argument could be that you might forget the environment variable set to the remote connection string, but then you just have to close the command window as soon as you complete migration. HTH

Comment: You could add the connection string in your secrets vault.  I wish EF Core's update database command had the -Connection parameter (I use the PowerShell's Update-Database and it lacks it too), but it only has the -Context (or -c here) switch, which forces us to use OnConfiguring, which is super cludgy.  Also, I should mention that if you are deploying to Azure, set a "ConnectionString" setting in Configuration on your app and it can be read via Environment.GetVariable().

Answer (score 2):

I solved it this way, inspired by [Javier Colombera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64807102/988133).

I ran the following on Windows in a Bash terminal and got the expected result:

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"
export ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="SslMode=Prefer;TrustServerCertificate=true;Host=<value>;Port=<value>;Database=<value>;Username=<value>;Password=<value>"
dotnet ef database update
```

This lets me avoid storing my production database connection string in version control, by overwriting the `ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection` value in `appsettings.json` via an environment variable.

Note that my project does not define a default connection string for the Staging and Production environments, only one is defined for the local Development environment.

Comment: can you please point me to documentation that lists all the available key-value options, such as ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection. I'm having a difficult time locating it.

Answer (score -6):

```
dotnet ef database update --configuration Debug
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is much more useful to OP and future readers if you add some explanation as to *why* and *how*

Comment: And when answering old, well answered questions you should also explain what your answer adds to the existing answers.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question, nor does it explain why you think it should.