# How do I specify a different dbcontext or sql user specifically for entity framework migrations only

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL Server database and am using Entity Framework 6 Code First.  I have a sql user with limited permissions for the application to use with the database, and a second user that has elevated permissions to use only for performing migrations.

My AppContext connection string works for using the application with a standard sql account, but when I run migrations, it should be using the MigrationContext connection string for the elevated user.

My DbContext.cs file:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext() : base("name=AppContext") { }

        *** Table Definitions ***

        static AppContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppContext, Configuration>("MigrationContext"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
           *** OnModelCreating code ***
        }
```

Please anyone, what am I doing wrong?

** EDIT **
I'm not looking to run this from the command line, I need this to work automatically on the server during MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Comment: You can specify the connection string in the command line with the option `--connection connection string here`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line connection string for EF core database update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398483/command-line-connection-string-for-ef-core-database-update)

Comment: I'll edit the post to clarify, I need this to happen automatically during the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion on the server.  Locally in the command line it's not an issue.