# Connectionstring via CLI for database update

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm learning about multi-tenancy, where each tenant has its own database.

The idea is by using the finbuckle NuGet package, it gets the connection string from the `appsettings.development.json`.

but for creating migrations and updating the database, the connection string has to be passed as an argument.

My database is via Docker with the command:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=myPassword" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlTest--hostname sqlTest -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

and using Azure Data Studio, I successfully connected to the database.

whenever I want to use the command:

```
dotnet ef database update -- --connection-string "Server=localhost,1433; Database=test; User Id=SA; Password=myPassword"
```

I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.MigrateUsingConnection(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, IMigrator migrator, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

I already tried multiple connection string formats, like putting the IP instead of localhost and adding the port to the server name. But I always end up with the same error, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: why -- -- after update?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [`--connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#usesqlserver-etc-accept-null) CLI option?

Comment: You are welcome to see if my answer helped or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played with your commands and I assume you are using Windows OS as I do. I found a few things in your attempt and here is my answer.

1. In your connection string as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965160/3088349) mentions you need to use `127.0.0.1\sqlTest` as server name.
2. In your dotnet command, you are using `-- --connection-string` which I think is a typo or something is not correct, check this answer [Command line connection string for EF core database update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398483/command-line-connection-string-for-ef-core-database-update).
3. Finally I got an issue with [A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (Error Number: 233)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ) and solved it by adding `TrustServerCertificate=True` to the connection string.
4. I used another password like `Qwer!234` instead of `myPassword` otherwise in docker the MSSQL server will return an error like: `ERROR: Unable to set a system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols`

So here are all the steps I did to make it work (my project with EF is named WebApplication1):

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Qwer!234" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlTest --hostname sqlTest -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project .\WebApplication1.csproj

dotnet ef database update --connection "Server=127.0.0.1\sqlTest,1433; User Id=sa; Password=Qwer!234; Database=test; TrustServerCertificate=True"
```

And connection string to Azure Data Studio is, the first time without a Database name because it has not been created yet:

```
Server=127.0.0.1\sqlTest,1433; User Id=sa; Password=Qwer!234;
```

But when a database is created you can use

```
Server=127.0.0.1\sqlTest,1433; User Id=sa; Password=Qwer!234; Database=test
```

Here is the screenshot of the results:

[image]

And Azure Data Studio:

[image]